# Castle Black - isn't it really just "Fort Black"?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle) (emphasis mine):

> A **castle** is a type of fortified structure built in Europe and the Middle East during the Middle Ages by European nobility. Scholars ... usually consider [the scope of the term] to be the private fortified residence of a lord or noble. This is distinct ... from a **fortress**, which was not always a residence for nobility; and from a fortified settlement...
>
> ... In its simplest terms, the definition of a castle accepted amongst academics is "a private fortified residence".

Castle Black is not the private residence of any Westerosi noble. Why, then, is Castle Black not merely a Fortress, like the Nightfort, for example?

One could argue that maybe the Lord Commander of the Night's Watch is the equivalent of a noble, but - traditionally, he would reside in the Nightfort, and that's not Castle Night or the Nightcastle. Also, neither fortress is "his", i.e. it's not a private residence in any way. So that can't be it.

Comment: The Night Fort may have been the first outpost on the wall, but it has long been since abandoned. The Lord Commander makes his residence at Castle Black.

Comment: @Skooba: That's a sad recent development. For most (?) of the last 8,000 years it wasn't like that.

Comment: Castle Black probably got its name thousands of years ago and the name stuck.

Comment: @RichS: You're making a [homunculus argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homunculus_argument). Plus, basically all of the forts along the wall were named thousands of years ago. The question is - why a Castle?

Comment: Because Castle Black sounds better than Fort Black

Comment: @einpoklum My hypothesis is not a homunculus argument, because the homunculus argument is based on infinite regression. I'm just saying the name was made years ago and stuck. Much like how Great Salt Lake is called a lake and not a sea (since seas are usually salt water and lakes are fresh water), but people called it the Great Salt Lake and not the Great Salt Sea and the name stuck. If you think my explanation is based on the homunculus argument, then show how it uses infinite regression.

Comment: @Edlothiad: That's possible, but it's not a very GRRM'ish reason.

Comment: @RichS: "Q: Why is Castle black named a castle (now)? A: Because it was named a castle (before)."

Comment: @einpoklum Saying it was called a castle before is not an example of infinite regression. There is a starting point where somebody misnamed it as a castle and the name stuck. Just like somebody first gave the Great Salt Lake its current name and the name stuck despite being inaccurate.

Comment: @RichS: So your regression is finite, wonderful :-(

Comment: @Bellatrix: ???

Comment: @RichS The question isn't "why is it called a castle *NOW*", its "why was it called a castle(in the first place)".  Your proposed answer does nothing to illuminate why whomever originally named it castle black did so.  (And no, the Homunculus Fallacy does not require infinite regression).

Comment: Even in the real world, what academics *now* use as an overarching definition of the distinction between a castle and a fort probably doesn't match up with how the people actually living with them used the terms in every instance, across many cultures over multiple centuries. I would expect there to be many counterexamples.

Comment: @Ben: Can you give an example for a structure similar to 'Castle' Black being called a Castle despite not being the fortified residence of a noble?

Comment: @einpoklum No; if I had some actual evidence I'd post an answer. It's just my intuition that it seems extremely unlikely that everyone even just in medieval Europe (let alone other eras and parts of the world where castles were used) consistently stuck to "the definition of a castle accepted amongst academics". Even if we were talking about a definition accepted amongst academics *at the time* real world language and place names would be unlikely to follow it perfectly. Human language just doesn't work that way.

Comment: @einpoklum you cut out this important part from your own link  *"Usage of the term has varied over time and has been applied to structures as diverse as hill forts and country houses."*

Answer (score 19):

You are correct, **[Castle Black](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Castle_Black)** is no true castle... this is because it does not have walls on all sides. I do not [think](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/castle) that having nobility there, while common, is a requirement. However, it does have a few thing that make it more castle-like:

- Towers: The Lord Commander's Tower, the King's Tower, The Lance, etc.
- The Lord Commander keeps his residence here. He may not a be a true "noble", but he does direct the general activities and has final say in decisions.
- Size: The castle and its buildings could once accommodate up to 5,000 men.
- It is the "entry point" for any southerner wishing to visit or join the Night't Watch.

Overall, Castle Black, despite how it portrayed in the TV series, is a large place deserving of its name.

---

Out of universe it was perhaps a style choice by GRRM in the main ASOIAF series;

- "Fort" appears 20 times (interestingly used a bit to describe the other fortifications along the wall...) - Does not include proper names like the Nightfort (35 times) or the Dreadfort (109 times).
- "Fortress" appears 19 times (mostly when describing Dragonstone or Harrenhal)
- "Castle" appears 1,194 times! Clearly the winner of the most common way to describe large buildings in Westeros.

Comment: +1 The scholarly definition of castle (as per the OP's quote) is different to common usage of the word - most people look at the castles of Wales, for example, and don't associate them with nobility.

Further, why expect the Westerosi to use modern English scholar definitions?

Comment: @HorusKol: This is supposed to be a comment on the question, not the answer.

Comment: @einpoklum it works as either...

Comment: Exactly you see a big stone walled structure with towers and what not you think castle not fort. The in universe reason is as you said but OOU it makes more sense to call it a castle as more people will recognise what castle means to what a fort means.